# Single Linked list implementation in Java

Tags: java

```
public class SinglyLinkedList implements Lista {
private final Element _headAndTail = new Element(null);
private int _size;

public SinglyLinkedList() {
    clear(); 
}

private static final class Element {

    private Object _value;
    private Element _next;

    public Element(Object value) {
        setValue(value);
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return _value;
    }

    public Element getNext() {
        return _next;
    }

    public void setNext(Element next) {
        assert next != null : "Wskaźnik na element następny nie może być pusty";
        _next = next;
    }

    public void attachBefore(Element e) {
        setNext(e);
        e.setNext(this);
    }
}

public void insert(int index, Object value)
        throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index < 0 || index > _size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    Element element = new Element(value);
    element.attachBefore(getElement(index));
    ++_size;
}

private Element getElement(int index) {
    return getElementForwards(index);
}

private Element getElementForwards(int index) {

    Element element = _headAndTail.getNext();
    for (int i = index; i > 0; --i)
        element = element.getNext();
    return element;
}

private void checkOutOfBounds(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size())
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}

public void add(Object value) {
    insert(size(), value);
}

public int size() {
    return _size;
}

public Object get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    checkOutOfBounds(index);
    return getElement(index).getValue();
}

public Object set(int index, Object value) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    checkOutOfBounds(index);
    Element element = getElement(index);
    Object oldValue = element.getValue();
    element.setValue(value);
    return oldValue;
}

public Object delete(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    checkOutOfBounds(index);
    Element element = getElement(index);
    --_size;
    return element.getValue();
}

public boolean delete(Object value) {
    Element e = _headAndTail.getNext();
    while (e != _headAndTail && !value.equals(e.getValue()))
        e = e.getNext();
    if (e != _headAndTail) {
        --_size;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public boolean contains(Object value) {
    return indexOf(value) != -1;
}

public void clear() {
    _headAndTail.setNext(_headAndTail);
    _size = 0;
}

public int indexOf(Object value) {
    int index = 0;
    Element e = _headAndTail.getNext();
    while (e != _headAndTail && !value.equals(e.getValue())) {
        e = e.getNext();
        ++index;
    }
    return e != _headAndTail ? index : -1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return _size == 0;
}

public Iterator iterator() {
    return new ValueIterator();
}

private final class ValueIterator implements Iterator {

    private Element _current = _headAndTail;

    public void first() {
        _current = _headAndTail.getNext();
    }

    public void last() {
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return _current == _headAndTail;
    }

    public void next() {
        _current = _current.getNext();
    }

    public void previous() {
    }

    public Object current() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (isDone())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        return _current.getValue();
    }
}
```

}

This is my code, it's compiling without any problems, i've made doubly linked list like this which worked without any problems, and when i changed it to singly it doesnt add objects into the list would be great if someone can take look - i think problem is methods `insert(int index, Object value)`, and `attachBefore(Element e)` in Element class.

Comment: Well what happens when you *do* call `size()`? Can you strip this down to a *short* but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I think this is a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger to step through your code and figure out for yourself where it's going wrong. In the long run, the effort will pay for itself many times over.

Comment: Change the title to reflect the exact issue. Seems kinda homework question.

Comment: hmm, size() doesn't seems to be working aswell

Comment: how about you taking a look at it using debugger and then asking a targeted question!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a conceptual problem in `Element.attachBefore(e)`.  Basically it is not possible to implement that method for a singly linked list.  Instead, you have to find the `Element` before the place where you want to insert, and insert the new `Element` *after* it.  (And deal with the special case where you are inserting at the start of the list.)

I'll leave you to work through the details ...

But Narendra's comment is spot on.  If you can't figure out what the current version of your code is doing, run it using your IDE's Java debugger and single step it through a call to the method that is giving you trouble.